# javascript function inverse text color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following javascript function that allows for a simple changing of the background theme for a webpage:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i=1;
    function colorTheme(){
        if(i%2==0){
            document.body.style.backgroundColor="white";
        }
        else{
            document.body.style.backgroundColor="#313030";
            document.body.style.color= white;
        }
        i++;
    }
</script>
<br>
<button onclick="colorTheme()">Click me</button>
```

When I alter my page's background theme to be black, I want to inverse the text color so that it is still readable for the entire page. I've read online that `document.body.style.color="whatever color you want"` is supposed to work for altering the text color for an entire webpage, however for some reason this is not working. Is there a reason why that line of code is not altering my entire webpage's text color to white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the color string i.e `white`

```
document.body.style.color= 'white'; //Quotes around the color
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9PtV8/2/)</kbd>

---

Also, it won't work in the scenarios where you've color specified for `div` or `p` elements because of the specificity and overriding inherited `color`

<kbd>[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/9PtV8/1/)</kbd> *(Here the `p` won't respect white color because `red` is set using CSS for `p` element, so won't inherit `body` elements color)*

It is better to swap the stylesheets instead of assigning `color` to `body` tag which won't work if `color` is applied to other elements as well.

---

As you commented that you are not sure what swapping of the stylesheet means, so you need to assign, say an `id` to the `<link>` tag like..

**HTML**

```
<link id="swapper" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css" />
```

Now create a swapper function like..

**JavaScript**

```
function swapper(select_sheet){
    document.getElementById('swapper').setAttribute('href', select_sheet);
}
```

Now call the function onClick to swap the stylesheets...

**HTML**

```
<button onClick="swapper('default.css')">Default</button>
<button onClick="swapper('stylesheet2.css')">Stylesheet 2</button>
```

Comment: I tried that previously, it does nothing with or without quotes

Comment: Oh!! I completely didn't think that scenarios where I've specified for elements like div would override. My entire CSS is overriding.. Also, what exactly do you mean by swapping stylesheets? I just picked up web programming about a week ago as a hobby and learning as I go

Comment: I didn't know you could do that, I'm definitely going to test this out, you've given me a ton of new ideas!

Comment: @Valrok make sure you paste the function at the very bottom of the page, say before the body closes, and wrap script tags around that :) if you get stuck then ping me, but you shouldn't get stuck as the solution is pretty  simple...

Comment: Ok. Just to make sure I understand it completely, by doing this I'm calling a different CSS to alter the webpage rather than forcing the entire body to be a specific color? Will I be able to put the HTML near the top of my body page or does that also need to be at the bottom?

Comment: @Valrok You do anything with your HTML, it won't matter, in this solution you are simply swapping entire stylesheet using JavaScript, so make sure you make two copies, and change the properties you want in other stylesheet, say different color, background etc...

Comment: One last question, I've tried making a second css stylesheet. I've put the javascript at the end of body and I currently am calling both CSS pages in my header and then at the start of body I am using the HTML code that you posted. When I test the buttons however, I am getting no response and it seems as though neither of the css sheets are being called. Is this because I reference several css sheets in my header (I am also using bootstrap's css sheet along with my own)?

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.mattlag.com/scripting/hexcolorinverter.php.  He's already done this.  Of course, you can't use a text string for colors, you have to use the hex code.